# Eclipse jdt: parse AST for IClassFile and no attached source

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I want to get the source of an IClassFile and parse it to an AST. I thought this is how you do it:

```
protected static CompilationUnit parse(IClassFile classFile) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setProject(classFile.getJavaProject());

    try {

        String source = classFile.getSource();
        parser.setSource(source.toCharArray());
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); // parse
}
```

But the `String` source is `null`. :(

Eclipse says I have to attach the source when I want to view the corresponding class, but in the outline I can see the correct ClassFile with all its methods, etc. So, there must be a way to parse an AST for an IClassFile without attached source (or does Eclipse attach the source programmatically?).

How can I get ASTNode of this IClassFile?

Comment: How are you retrieving the `IClassFile`?

Comment: I think you are using an old version. newParser(AST.JLS3); means java version 3. you should go with core manipulation v1.5.0 v20130605